# Statistical method to compare urban vs rural matched siblings

Tags: statistics, stata

I am writing a study protocol for my masters thesis. The study seeks to compare the rates of Non Communicable Diseases and risk factors and determine the effects of rural to urban migration. Sibling pairs will be identified from a rural area. One of the siblings should have participated in the rural NCD survey which is currently on going in the area. The other sibling should have left the area and reported moving to a city.Data will collected by completing a questionnaire on demographics, family history,medical history, diet,alcohol consumption, smoking ,physical activity.This will be done for both the rural and urban sibling, with data on the amount  of time spent in urban areas fur

The outcomes which are binary (whether one has a condition or not) are : 1.diabetic, 2.hypertensive, 3.obese

What statistical method can I use to compare the outcomes (stated above) between the two groups, considering that the siblings were matched (one urban sibling for every rural sibling)?

What statistical methods can also be used to explore associations between amount spent in urban residence and the outcomes?

Comment: I think this is better on Cross Validated or some other forum.

Comment: You have now posted at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231423/statistical-method-to-compare-urban-vs-rural-matched-siblings as suggested, but note advice at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic about not cross-posting implying that you should delete this post.

Comment: However, as there is now an answer, you should leave the question as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your main aim is to compare quantities of two nominal distributions, a chi-square test seems to be the method of choice with regard to your first question. However, it should be mentioned that a chi-square test is somehow "the smallest" test for answering differences in samples. If you are studying medicine (or related) a chi-square test is fine because it is also frequently applied by researchers of this field. If you are studying psychology or sociology (or related) I'd advise to highlight limitations of the test in the discussions section since it mostly tests your distributions against randomly expected distributions.

Regarding your second question, a logistic regression would be applicable since it allows binomial distributed variables both for independent variables (predictors) and dependent variables. However, if you have other interval scaled variables (e.g. age, weight etc.) you could also use t-tests or ANOVAs to investigate differences between these variables with respect to the existence of specific diseases (i.e. is diabetic or not).

Overall, this matter strongly depends on what you mean by "association". Classically, "association" refers to correlations or linear regression (for which you need interval scaled variables on "both sides") but given your data structure, the aforementioned methods possess a better fit.

How you actually calculate these tests depends on the statistics software used.

Comment: This statistical advice belongs better on the Cross Validated version of this version.

Comment: Some questionable or obscure remarks here. Association has been used for many decades in statistical sciences to include association of categorical variables; its **not** necessarily implying correlation or linear relation is precisely why it's a useful term, which is the reverse of what you suggest.

Comment: The advice that chi-square tests make more sense in medicine than in psychology or sociology is puzzling, to say the least.

Comment: Well, I guess some things were understood wrong here. Sorry for that. I just meant to refer to my (very subjective) observation that "association" is frequently used synonymously to "relationship" which suggests to investigate similarities or influences over correlations or regression instead of looking for differences between conditions.

Comment: And yes, it is nonsense to say that a chi-square test is more or less useful in any of the mentioned disciplines. It's just more **accepted** in medicine, whereas other fields try to a priori design experiments in a way that more sophisticated methods are applicable (which doesn't seem to be the case here).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. At the great risk of seeming to quibble, I think medical researchers and statisticians use experimental ideas immensely more often than sociologists! What's a clinical trial? But we seem close to agreement.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. But I guess that dependent on the research question, sociologists need to use the same or at least related methods once in a while when conducting empirical research.

Comment: @rectus if this answer helped, please consider selecting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark. This lets community know the answer worked and the issue is closed.